# How to make getattr() and __dict__ take str() argument?

Tags: python, class, dictionary, attributes, getattr

Using the code:

```
class Values():
    # class for storing values
    value_1 = None

print(Values.value_1)
print(getattr(Values, 'value_1'))
```

I am able to get Output:

```
None
None
```

But when trying to use this code it does not work for any of them:

```
print(Values.__dict__.get(str(value_1)))
print(getattr(Values, str(value_1)))
print(Values.__dict__[str(value_1)])
```

I get Output:

```
NameError: name 'value_1' is not defined
```

I am trying to access the attribute this way for a future project and the other two ways will not suffice. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. The error is telling you the name is not defined and it's correct. Instead use: `print(Values.__dict__.get('value_1'))` and it works as expected. Wrapping an undefined name in `str()` does not make it a string. It's hard to imagine a situation where you could write code like `str(value_1)` and could not write `'value_1'` instead.

Comment: Is there a way I can make it a string other than the quotations? How can I pass a variable with the same name as value_1 to get the output None?

Comment: You just define the variable: `some_var = 'value_1'`. Then you can use it `Values.__dict__.get(some_var)`.

Comment: What if I had a set of values, ie value_1, value_2, value_3 etc. that were all attributes of Values(), would that still be the best way? Thank you

Comment: If you have ordered names like `value_1`, `value_2` etc. it sound like the best way is a list: `values = ['a', 'b', 'c']` then you just access them `values[0], values[1]`...etc.

Comment: This seems to be the best way! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`value_1` is not defined, you need to put in quotes.
Here:

```py
print(Values.__dict__.get(str(value_1)))
print(getattr(Values, str(value_1)))
print(Values.__dict__[str(value_1)])
```

You are acting as if `value_1` is a predefined variable. You cannot have random text in python without it being a environment variable, or a variable that you have defined.
This:

```py
print(Values.__dict__.get(str('value_1')))
print(getattr(Values, str('value_1')))
print(Values.__dict__[str('value_1')])
```

would work.
This:

```py
value_1 = 'value_1'
print(Values.__dict__.get(str(value_1)))
print(getattr(Values, str(value_1)))
print(Values.__dict__[str(value_1)])
```

would also work.